# QGIS 2.6.1 Brighton/ Grass pluggin r.stream.xxxx

Tags: qgis, grass-gis

I just updated my OSGeo4W and now have QGIS 2.6.1 and GRASS 6.4.4 and am trying to get strahler stream order.

I am figuring out GRASS 6.4.4 GUI by itself but GRASS is easier withing QGIS, however, I opened the GRASS GUI & used "FETCH" to obtain all the latest tools needed and I have found 'help' files that state people are using the r.stream.xxx tools through QGIS, however I cannot find them in the GRASS Tools modules list with in QGIS? I have not been able to use them. I have a process down that runs fast, but only up to the WATERSHED tool, I have not figured out how to get Strahler order from those outputs withing QGIS?

Answer (score 1):

If you're wanting to use GRASS within QGIS, you can use GRASS tools from the QGIS **Processing Toolbox** which contains tools from QGIS, GRASS and many others:

[image: Processing toolbox for r.stream]

[image: Processing toolbox for strahler order]

Make sure the folder paths are correct for each provider via *Processing* > *Options and configuration* > *Providers*

Comment: Thanks - I did not look at the processing toolbar since I upgraded and was trying to work in GRASSTools. This is great.

Comment: @als, most welcome buddy and hope you get the results you want!

Comment: this might need to be a different thread- i found the r.streams. which I knew would need a flow direction - so I ran r.watershed. great outputs - but the default names nor output names  do not match up with the requirements for input in r.streams.order??? any idea where I can find that information - for example. r.stream.order input states 'stream mask' - i also need to be able to figure out which file is the flow accumulation & then how to set the threashold in the accumulation file for strahler order. There are several ways to get strahler order and I am looking for a good workflow.